# Show and hide a div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm facing an issue, issue is I've a product page where image thumbnails are appearing, 
i want when user hover or mouseenter on any thumnail the associated 'add to cart' button should appear, current when i mouseenter on any product all 'add to cart' buttons are appearing,
link is: http://etekstudio.org/demo/crateen/en/men
cod is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var target = jQuery('.product-image');
jQuery(target).mouseenter(function(){
            jQuery('.popUpPrice button ').show();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".product-image").hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).find(".popupPrice button").show();
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).find(".popupPrice button").hide();
    });
});
```

That way it hides it on mouse exit as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var target = jQuery('.product-image');
    target.mouseenter(function(){
        jQuery(this).find('.popUpPrice button').show();
    });
});
```

Also `target` is already a jQuery object. You can just use `target.mouseenter` instead of `jQuery(target).mouseenter`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery(".product-image").mouseenter(function(){
    jQuery('.popUpPrice button').show();
});
```

use hover in jquery

```
jQuery(".product-image").hover(
  function() {
           jQuery('.popUpPrice button ').show();
    }, function() {
            jQuery('.popUpPrice button ').hide();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         jQuery('.product-image').hover(function(){
                jQuery(this).next('.popUpPrice').find('button').show();
         },function(){
                jQuery(this).next('.popUpPrice').find('button').hide();
         });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

And you also don't have need to create new object with the name `target`.You an do directly with this way also.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.product-image').mouseenter(function(){
        jQuery(this).find('.popUpPrice button').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.product-image').hover(function(){
$(this).next('.popUpPrice').find('.disc button').show();
},function(){
$(this).next('.popUpPrice').find('.disc button').hide();
});
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f2W9b/5/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     var target = jQuery('.product-image'); 
     target.each (function () {
         jQuery(this).mouseenter(function(){
              jQuery(this).find('.popUpPrice button').show()
         });
     });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

inside the function

you are selecting all elements with '.popUpPrice button', you must find the correct button to show.

in this html structure, for instance:

```
<div class="product">
    <div class="product-image><img src="" /></div>
    <div class="popUpPrice"><button>Add to cart</button></div>
</div>
```

all you have to do is:

```
jQuery('.product-image').mouseenter(function(evt) {
    var target = jQuery(evt.currentTarget);
    target.parent().find('.popUpPrice button').show();
});
```

evt.currentTarget is the element which triggered the event. In this case will always be .product-image